# Are lambda value objects?

Tags: c#-3.0, lambda, equals

As I understand 2 lambdas should be equal as long as they declare the same code in the same order with the same parameters.

But a simple test on GetHashcode fails:

`$`

```
    private class LambdaTest 
    {
        private bool x;

        public Expression<Func<object, bool>> Predicate
        {
            get { return o => x; }
        }

        public LambdaTest(bool x)
        {
            this.x= x;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Predicate.GetHashCode();
        }

    }
```

`$`

Test
`$`

```
    [Test]
    public void hashonlambdas()
    {
        NullSpecification n1 = new NullSpecification(true);
        NullSpecification n2 = new NullSpecification(true);

        Assert.AreEqual(n1.GetHashCode(), n2.GetHashCode());
    }
```

`$`

Can you tell me if Im doing something wrong or maybe lambdas are not value objects

Comment: How is LambdaTest related to NullSpecification?

Comment: I thought a lambda expression was a delegate. Regardless, is it equality or same object that you should be testing for.

Comment: The sample code is just an extract of my real code (i think i remove some parts that make it not very clear). But the focus is in that Predicate property is basically the same in both objects so Predicate.GetHashCode() must return the same if they are Equals.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because lambdas are delegates and Delgate is a Reference Type.
You can have two delegates of the same type but with distinct invocation list, and they are not the same. In case of lambda, even if they do the same work, if you call one you are not calling the other.